# memcpy and free in c

Tags: c

```
psApdu->prgbCData = (byte_t*)malloc(APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH);
memset((void*)psApdu->prgbCData, 0, APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH);

byte_t prgData[] = { 0x01, 0x38, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02 };
memcpy((byte*)psApdu->prgbCData, prgData, sizeof(prgData));

free(psApdu->prgbCData);
```

'free' statement failing here. What is the reason?

Comment: How is `APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH` defined?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: What do you mean "failing?" Is it causing a segfault?

Comment: what is the value for APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH?

Comment: If the size of `prgData` is larger than `APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH` then the call to `memcpy` will copy data beyond the end of the allocated area. This might get the call to `free` to fail.

Comment: The problem probably lies in the code between memcpy and free, which you have omitted from the question.

Comment: you could use calloc instead of malloc that is the same as doing malloc/memset

Comment: Well, then the problem is almost certainly in the code you're *not* showing us.  The code that's stepping on your buffer :)

Comment: yes. I apologize, in the middle some codes were there. I thought it had no efect on SIZE. but I was wrong. I am sorry. size was the issue and its solved now. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't cast to and from `void *`. Also `sizeof` is an operator.

You need to check that `sizeof prgData <= APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH`. You could try this with a static assertion:

```
psApdu->prgbCData = malloc(APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH);
memset(psApdu->prgbCData, 0, APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH);

byte_t prgData[] = { 0x01, 0x38, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02 };
_Static_assert(sizeof prgData <= APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH, "too big");
memcpy(psApdu->prgbCData, prgData, sizeof prgData);

free(psApdu->prgbCData);
```

Comment: perhaps you should mention that `_Static_assert` is C11 and only available in a few compilers, yet? Also, that there is a macro `static_assert` for everyday use that has a spelling that is a bit more user friendly?

Comment: @Jens: boost includes `STATIC_ASSERT` for non-C++11 compliant compilers, though I'd just copy paste the macro, using boost for one marco is overkill...

Comment: @Necrolis, boost is C++, here we are on C, I was talking about C11 and not C++11. You are right this feature is easily emulated, but an answer that uses it should at least mention how to obtain it.

Comment: @Jens: right you are, in which case, I amend my comment to "blatantly copy the C macro from boost for non C11 compilers" :P

Comment: Well to be fair it is 2012, and so the C11 standard is behind us. I don't think it's unreasonable to make use of its features and backport where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested changes:

```
  byte_t prgData[] = { 0x01, 0x38, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02 };
  int ilen = sizeof (prgData);
  if (ilen > APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH) {
    printf ("ERROR: expected %d bytes, got %d\n", APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH, ilen);
    return;
  }

  psApdu->prgbCData = (byte_t*)malloc(APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH);
  if (!psApdu->prgbCData) {
    printf ("ERROR: Unable to malloc(%d) bytes...\n", APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH);
    return;
  }

  memset((void*)psApdu->prgbCData, 0, APDU_BUFFER_LENGTH);
  memcpy((byte*)psApdu->prgbCData, prgData, sizeof(prgData));
  free(psApdu->prgbCData);
```

ALSO:
If you successfully allocate the data, make sure nothing "steps" on it.

Q: Are "memset()/memcpy()" the only two functions that update psApdu->prgbCData?  Is there anything else that writes to this buffer?  Like filling in colors to your color table or pixels to your image array, for example?

Comment: Why would you compare constants at runtime? Why would you bother to check for memory failure, let alone not return an error value to indicate something failed? Why are you casting pedantically?

Comment: @Matt Joiner - For whatever it's worth, I was just trying to use as much of the OP's original code as possible, to best illustrate  what should be changed.  It looks like his malloc()'s "rgbData[]" is a pixel array, so it's likely the *real* problem is overwriting the buffer when he writes his pixels.  So ironically, *neither* of our comments really address the actual problem.  I was just trying to be helpful.  Youre right - I failed.  Miserably...